# Equations of Motion for Particle in Potential Field

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have a question about the formulation of the equation of motion of a particle moving through a given vector field. Let's say, the position of the particle at time t is denoted by $q(t)$, and the vector field is given through the scalar potential $V:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. I have seen two different equations of motion, namely
\begin{equation}
\frac{d q(t)}{d t} = - \nabla V(q(t)) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 q(t)}{d t^2}= -\nabla V(q(t)). \tag{2}
\end{equation}
I might have misunderstood the meaning of the function $V$ in one of the settings, but I hope, that you can clarify, which equation is the correct one in which setting. (Does one of the equations include inertia which the other one does not?).

Comment: Well, Newton's equations are second order, aren't they?

Comment: Where did you see the first?

Comment: I saw the first in a talk by a mathematician about stochastic systems. The time evolution of a stochastic system in mathematics is always modeled by first order equations. Or do they not model moving particles?

Comment: @Luke It's highly like that the mathematician is using $q$ to refer to a generalized state variable for the system rather than position; if he was talking about position, the potential function $V$ refers to something other than energy. Was there any indication within the talk that he meant $q$ to mean position and $V$ to mean potential energy?

Comment: @Luke Also, $V$ is a scalar field, not a vector field.

Comment: @probably_someone Are the equations of motion for generalized coordinates of first order? The speaker did not refer to $V$ as the energy or anything, I was just trying to interpret the meaning of $V$ in the first equation, and trying to understand why mathematicians mostly study first order equations (maybe my perception is wrong regarding this).

Comment: @Luke Did the mathematician actually call this equation an "equation of motion"? In any case, even if he did, it's not guaranteed that the phrase "equation of motion" even has the same meaning in physics and in mathematics. After all, we consistently use different terminology elsewhere, for example in our use of the word "tensor" (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2624411/).

Comment: @probably_someone I don't remember exactly what she said. I think she drew a double well potential and then said that the state moves towards one of the fixed points. I guess, she was not talking about a physical movement but rather about the behavior of the solution of the equation (which does not seem to describe a motion of a particle).

Comment: @Luke It's also worth noting that, in the Hamiltonian dynamics, equations of motion _are_ first-order (where the first-order derivative is applied to the generalized momentum). There are also twice as many of them as there are in Lagrangian dynamics.